# Ran codesign -fs - /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app how do I reverse it?

Tags: bootcamp, code-signing

I ran `codesign -fs - /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app` as per [a post here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105588/anyone-with-experience-in-hacking-the-codesigning-on-os-x)  and now I cannot launch Bootcamp Assistant at all. Is there a terminal command I can run to reverse this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no undo; permanent changes are made. The only way to resolve this situation would be to replace Boot Camp Assistant with a known-good copy. A simple way to do that is to reinstall OS X using Recovery Mode.

Comment: That's a pity. Would obtaining a fresh copy of bootcamp asst. work or is this a change made outside of the bootcamp resources?

Comment: @user2528531 The code signing is done on the .app package, and restoring this should be fine since you did not create a specific certificate or any other external resources to perform this. If you have a Time Machine backup, you can use this to restore the file. Alternatively, use an OS X installer and Pacifist to extract the Boot Camp Assistant.

Comment: Thanks very much. That worked although I can't copy the restored version to the utilities directory because it won't let me over write the original. It works run from another directory though.

Comment: hey man same problem happened to me can you share the bootcamp in drive ?